# How to use varargs as the parameter of Constructor.getConstructor( ) in java

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, variadic-functions

I have a java class like below which I want to create an instance of this class dynamically by using class name.

```
class Demo {
    public Demo(String... s) {
    //some initialization here.
    }
}
```

And I want to create an object using following code

```
Class<?> klass = Class.forName("Demo");

Constructor<?> con = klass.getConstructor("**what should be here**");

Object obj = con.newInstance(param1, param2, ...);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`String...` is just `String[]` so you can use

```
Constructor<?> con = klass.getConstructor(String[].class);
```

Note that you need to invoke the constructor like

```
Object o = con.newInstance((Object) new String[] {"first", "second", "more"});
```

with the cast to `(Object)` for a varargs invocation.