# Constructor.newInstance(): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, classloader

I have the following class:

```
public class DefaultContainer extends AbstractContainer {

private JobBeanFactory jobBeanFactory;

private ScheduleManager scheduleManager;

/**
 * for local
 * @param classLoader
 * @param packagesToScan
 */
public DefaultContainer(ClassLoader classLoader, String packagesToScan) {
    super(classLoader, packagesToScan);
    this.jobBeanFactory = new DefaultJobBeanFactory();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(classLoader);
    this.scheduleManager = new DefaultScheduleManager(configuration, this.jobBeanFactory, getJobScanner().getJobDescriptorList());
}

/**
 * for remote
 * @param configuration
 * @param packagesToScan
 * @param jarUrls
 */
public DefaultContainer(Configuration configuration, String packagesToScan, String... jarUrls) {
    super(packagesToScan, jarUrls);
    this.jobBeanFactory = new DefaultJobBeanFactory();
    this.scheduleManager = new DefaultScheduleManager(configuration, this.jobBeanFactory, getJobScanner().getJobDescriptorList());
}


public ScheduleManager scheduleManager() {
    return scheduleManager;
}

}
```

Then, I use reflection to load and create a class instance.

```
Class<Container> containerClass = (Class<Container>) classLoader.loadClass("xxxxx.DefaultContainer");
Constructor<Container> containerConstructor = containerClass.getConstructor(Configuration.class, String.class, String[].class);
container = containerConstructor.newInstance(getConfiguration(), packagesToScan, new String[]{jarUrl});
```

But when executing a method of newInstance, then I get an exception:

```
com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.core.exception.NiubiException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.cluster.node.AbstractRemoteJobNode.createContainer(AbstractRemoteJobNode.java:100)
at com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.cluster.node.AbstractRemoteJobNode.getContainer(AbstractRemoteJobNode.java:67)
at com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.cluster.node.MasterSlaveNode.executeOperation(MasterSlaveNode.java:264)
at com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.cluster.node.MasterSlaveNode.access$1000(MasterSlaveNode.java:56)
at com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.cluster.node.MasterSlaveNode$3.childEvent(MasterSlaveNode.java:253)
at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:516)
at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:510)
at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:507)
at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$9.run(PathChildrenCache.java:759)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.zuoxiaolong.niubi.job.cluster.node.AbstractRemoteJobNode.createContainer(AbstractRemoteJobNode.java:98)
    ... 19 more
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I make sure the parameter types are all matched with [Configuration.class,String.class,String[].class]

Comment: Are you sure `getConfiguration()` returns the same `Configuration` class as the constructor's parameter? Have you checked `packagesToScan` is indeed a `String`?

Comment: Also you are explicitly casting your class as `Class<Container>`. If `Container` is a class, does it have a matching constructor?

Comment: Yes, I sure. I has debug the program , and look at the program's runtime detail.It does match.

Comment: I eval the expressions ,then all return true. etc. Configuration.class==getConfiguration().getClass,packagesToScan.getClass()==String.class.

Comment: I have tried to change the last parameter type to String,then eval expression jarUrl.getClass() == String.class .It always return true ,but still throw the exception(type mismatch).

Comment: Have you tried using `DefaultContainer` instead of `Container` as mentioned above? I.e. does `Container` have the same constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast your `String array` to `Object`. It should help.

```
containerConstructor.newInstance(getConfiguration(), packagesToScan, (Object) new String[]{ jarUrl });
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277367/how-to-use-varargs-as-the-parameter-of-constructor-getconstructor-in-java) someone had the same problem: